# How can I infer the child property types of an extended Generic type?

Tags: typescript, extends, typescript-generics

I'd like to write a function that returns a property of an extended generic type. Is it even possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```
interface Animal {
    readonly weight: {total: number}
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    readonly weight: {total: number, tail: number, head: number, body: number }
}


const getWeight = <T extends Animal>(animal: T) => {
    return animal.weight
}

const myDog = { weight: { total: 20, tail: 5, head: 5, body: 10 } }

const myDogsWeight = getWeight<Dog>(myDog)

// Property 'head' does not exist on type '{ total: number; }'.
const myDogsHeadWeight = myDogsWeight.head
```

If I try to explicitly annotate the return type of the function, I get another error:

```
type InferredWeight<TAnimal> = TAnimal extends { readonly weight: infer U } ? U : never
type DogWeight = InferredWeight<Dog> // <-- This type works correctly

const getWeightTyped = <T extends Animal>(animal: T): InferredWeight<T> => {
    // Type '{ total: number; }' is not assignable to type 'InferredWeight<T>'.
    return animal.weight
}
```

Here's a [playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkoI4ATAexBwE9kB3CYAcwAswAuAsasLl4gArpgBG0AL6EZhUJFiIUAEWptkEAB6QQlAM5oM2PEVJkKNOoxbsuvfP0E5hYyVAA0yQcBfJREtBeHJaugZ7I4tSU9GHuyDJyhAi0+mDIbBBgAOqsnOkAvMgAPAAqmjoQeoboWLgAfAAUcMZCyKUAlMgF9QTEpORgIlAgyC11OAB0tvmyhMmp6Zj0ahpF+Mx59gTeAm0ATAAMXj5+AKzBocgXkdGxyACMhwkJ8ykgacjLq-q5doUZLJ-fLFVZNb7qDrzAD00OQAAUoNQAA7QMCMADkISoGOQNAghhAAgqwE+tG89FRyAxGycbQC7gA3AkMZMFh8lit1PoABKWYFcbpfLlsX5bMCTbGUeYy9FUgCSIBg0HIlAFYDKtRMvSKpS1uAqugMO3IVFoDE2-14oGVUGQAFUXgB+B3IYQQABu0EIctU6nVQsVttV6tB6nqb0WgJy4tKlIglCFZUNVWN+pwTXGJl4nV4QZVCdDpR1vTMpFh7Xj1Npez8DOgzKkuNJ-mJcH0+nYIDg4hwKH4FKpGPzUBD4rK9VZ-RIg2GoyzuGm4tkQA).

The only TypeScript Github issue that seems relevant is [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995), but it is an issue with union types.

Comment: Try using a lookup type like `T['weight']` instead of using a conditional type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @jcalz you can use a lookup type:

This should do what you are looking for.

```
interface Animal {
  readonly weight: { total: number }
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  readonly weight: { total: number, tail: number, head: number, body: number }
}

const getWeight = <
  T extends Animal
>(animal: T): T['weight'] => {
  return animal.weight
}

const myDog = { weight: { total: 20, tail: 5, head: 5, body: 10 } }

const myDogsWeight = getWeight(myDog);
```